# A $_SESSION variable is not displaying its value when using var_dump()

Tags: php

I have a piece of code below where it contains `$_SESSION` variables:

```
if (isset($_POST['id'])) {

$_SESSION['id'] = $_POST['id'];

}

if(isset($_SESSION['sessionNum'])){
            //Declare my counter for the first time

            $_SESSION['initial_session'] = $_SESSION['sessionNum'];
            $_SESSION['sessionNumber'] = intval($_SESSION['sessionNum']);
            $_SESSION['sessionCounting'] = 1;

    }
```

...

```
ASSESSMENT: (<?php echo $assessment ?>) TOTAL ASSESSMENTS: <?php echo $_SESSION['initial_session'] ?>
```

The above statement displays this:

```
ASSESMENT: (WESSF)  TOTAL ASSESSMENTS: 2
```

But two pages down the line (completesession.php) I want to use couple of those `$_SESSION` variables. Problem though is that if I do a `var_dump($_SESSION['sessionNum'])` then it only `int(1)` but not the value `2`. Yet it does output `(WESSF)` for `var_dump($_SESSION['id'])`. Why is this?

Below is the completesession.php) page:

```
<?php

ini_set('session.gc_maxlifetime',12*60*60);
ini_set('session.gc_divisor', '1');
ini_set('session.gc_probability', '1');
ini_set('session.cookie_lifetime', '0');
require_once 'init.php'; 

error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set('display_errors', 1);

session_start();

  var_dump($_SESSION['id']);
  var_dump($_SESSION['sessionNum']);

?>
```

Comment: here did you actually _set_ `$_SESSION['sessionNum']`? I am seeing various reads from it, but no writes

Comment: @MichaelBerkowski He has sessionNum and sessionNumber. I bet that's causing some confusion.

Comment: But anyway, `var_dump()` on an integer variable will only display something like `int(val)`, so 1 _is_ the value.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You might be looking in the wrong session key here. Use:

```
var_dump($_SESSION);
```

to display all sessions keys.

Also the code you've posted is not counting up any number, so the number `1` looks correct (with the few I can see), and `2` would not be correct.

A final note: Because you can successfully see `int(1)` it shows that the session feature in your PHP setup is actually working. So you might have just made some mistake somewhere to set the correct key/value.